# Is it possible to set message board as a notification in Workflow with Kaleo in liferay?

Tags: liferay-6, messageboard

I am working in Liferay. Recently I have developed 3 level workflow using Kaleo in liferay for reviewing the content. But what happens is when user who submit any content then the users related in the chain will be notified through mail. But I want something different if possible. What i wish is, put one MessageBoard on the Home Screen then whenever anyone post content the users will get the notification in the MessageBoard. The idea is you can say somewhat to facebook. That whenever your friend post a comment you get notification via mail as well as you get notification on the home screen of your account. Is it possible to achieve the same thing in Liferay using Kaleo Workflow or anyother way to do this?

Valuable suggestions are welcomed.......

Thanks

Comment: @Martin Gamulin, Hi. Can you please help me in this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notification from MessageBoard your user can click on Subscribe link and should get mail.

For yout other (facebook like) requirements liferay has few built in portlets that do that (I'm not facebook user so I guess): Friends, Friends Activities, Requests, Wall, Summary. Note that these can only be added to your users pages (public/private).

You even have Activities portlet that displays all community users activities.

If this is not what you are looking for let me know.

Comment: I got the point. I need user's private page and through there i can get these all the things. Thanks for your reply...